# How to store properties in client in order to restart when disconnnected from Spring Config Server

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

I have used Spring Cloud Config Client with Spring Config Server, but it loses the latest config server when the client restarts. Is there any way to store it?

I hope just like below the client can restart with latest config even if the server is offline.

```
client   ----pull config ----------------------->  server (is running)
client   --- refresh and save config------------>  server (is running)
client   ---client can restart with saved config   server (is offline)
client   --- refresh and save config------------>  server (is running)
```

or is there any other technology to implement this logic?

Comment: I was going through config server in last couple of weeks, have not come across any already implemented option for this. It needs a custom implementation I believe.